# how to map entity with dynamic Table from database?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are similar table in my database st_tickets_1, st_tickets_2, st_tickets_3 and so on that can be generated as per need. I want to map these table with the single Entity. But I can not map because I have to put the static table name over entity @Table("st_tickets_1").

for as of now i am doing using Spring JDBC templet.

Answer (score 1):

You may found useful hibernate inheritance features:

https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/mapping-inheritance-in-hibernate

So it is possible to create the abstract entity which contains id and common fields:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Ticket {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And implemenations for different tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "st_ticket1")
public class Ticket1 extends Ticket {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "st_ticket2")
public class Ticket2 extends Ticket {
}
```

Than read implementation instances from a DB and cast them to `Ticket` abstraction to use it for business logic.